# i want to swipe right and left in swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

i have a project in xcode 7 ( swift ) that i want to load differents viewscontrollers designeds in storyboard with the function swipe right and left and go to next viewcontroller or back.
Now i have this but only fade in right to left and i want the two fade ins.

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    switch sender.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
        print("SWIPED DERECHA")
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cambio2", sender: nil)
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
        print("SWIPED IZQUIERDA")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cambio", sender: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use UISwipeGestureRecognizer by creating 2 instance of it.
one for each direction.

```
    var swipeLeft : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:")
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left

    var swipeRight : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

and the swipe function

```
func swipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    switch sender.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
        print("SWIPED DERECHA")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("first", sender: nil)
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
        print("SWIPED IZQUIERDA")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers after the school i will try i want to create an effect fade in to right and fade in to left when i swipe one of to directions i think that must be try navigstioncontroller with animation

Comment: For Swift3: change "UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left" to "UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left" and "swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right" to "swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right" in the registration as well in the swipe() function. Also change "self.performSegueWithIdentifier("first", sender: nil)" to "self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "first", sender: nil)" and "self.performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: nil)" to "self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: nil)".

Answer (score 2):

You're going about this all wrong. You need to look into interactive custom transitions. So, for example, if you want to swipe left and right to mean push and pop in a navigation controller, then implement the navigation controller's delegate's `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:` and `navigationController:interactionControllerForAnimationController:` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer` should only has one direction allowed, you should use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

```
let swipe = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe);


func respondToSwipeGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = sender.velocityInView(self.view)
        //left or right
        if point.x > 0 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue1", sender: nil)
        }else{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue2", sender: nil)
        }
```

Of course both controllers should be in `UINavigationController`

For Storyboard settings:
[image]

Comment: i succeded with uigesture recognizer but the transition between viewcontroller only work in one direction i want to create a typical magazine inside an app like the views of pdf in ibooks